# idiomatic way of extending clojure reify

Tags: clojure

So far, this is the solution I've found but I believe it's not very idiomatic ...

any better suggestions to dynamically extend reify?

**UPDATE!**
My idea would be adding a debugging call to println before the execution of certains functions of a current reify implementation.On the example provided i add a short string to the current implementation. Other cases could be timming or commons aspects that you can find on AspectOrientedProgramming

Thanks!

```
(def r (let [f "foo"]
         (reify Object
           (toString [this]
             f))))

(str r) ; == "foo"


(def r-extended (let [f "extended"]
         (reify Object
           (toString [this]
             (str f "-"(str r))))))

(str r-extended) ; == "extended-foo"
```

Comment: Please add some prose as to why you need to extend `reify` - what goal are you really trying to solve?

Comment: Good idea @Shepmaster ! Now it is updated with a description problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell your goal is to wrap an object created by reify and inject new behavior on calls to that object.

One direction would be to write a macro that takes the place of reify and inserts an "around" call for every reified function to a function you provide. Use would maybe look like this:

```
(reifyw Object wrapf
  (toString [this]
    f)))
```

which would turn into:

```
(reify Object
  (toString [this] 
    (wrapf f)))
```

Another direction would be to just wrap calls to the object's interface to insert your own dynamic behavior - that would be done at the point of use instead of the point of declaration which has tradeoffs.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! can i ask you for a schematic code for describing the last direction, I don't quite understand it